# How to generate UUID in android using device id and current timestamp

Tags: android, guid, uuid

In my android application i want to create uuid for identifier primary key in each table entry so that it should be unique among 1000's of users in my server.So whenever a new record is inserted a random uuid/guid should be generated with the device id,current timestamp,etc. to the identifier field instead of a auto-generated integer value.How can i do that in android? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To build a unique UUID, you should use the [UUID class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html):

> String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

It is already based on the current timestamp and does not rely on any personally identifiably information such as device id (most of which require a runtime permission).

Comment: does this produce the same uuid for multiple device have the same timestamp??

Comment: what are the other things this random uuid depends on other than timestamp to make this unique across devices??

Comment: Any reply?? i likes to know how this UUID.randomUUID().toString() becomes unique across multiple devices

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc on the class? It goes into great detail and includes links to the RFC

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually generate a UUID based on the timestamp (which would be version 1), as the poster asks, it generates a type 4 random UUID.  "Static factory to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID. The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator."